# How to get one field of every document of a collection on Firestore?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, ionic4

I'm trying to get **just one** field of every document of one collection. What i'm doing is to do a subscribe method to fill a list for a dynamic filter, but i know it doesnt work, what is the best way to get just what i want? I would like to be subscribed to it, here is my code:

```
this.af.collection('objects').valueChanges().subscribe(data => {        
  this.listTitles.push(data.title)
});
```

Comment: At the end i fixed it, the only thing that i do is get subscribed to the all data, and then just show on the list down of filter the titles, also i'm using an auxiliar array to make it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.subscribe` won't work in your case, probably you need to split your code like this,

```
this.objectCollectionRef = this.af.collection('objects');
this.objectCollection = this.objectCollectionRef.valueChanges();


for(let data of this.objectCollection){
   this.listTitles.push(data.title)
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Does the `this.objectCollection` contain any data (or) it is coming as null?

Comment: What happens when you interpolate your `listTitles` as `{{listTitles}}` and display in your `html`?

Comment: Type 'Observable<unknown[]>' is not an array type or a string type.ts(2495)         
   (this objectCollection)....

Answer (score -1):

Just map the result and use async in your template

```ts
class YourComponent{
  listTitles:Observable<String>;

  constructor(){
    this.listTitles = this.af.collection('objects').valueChanges().pipe(
      map(objs => objs.map(obj => obj.title))
    )
  }
}
```

And in your template :

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of listTitles | async">
 <!-- have fun -->
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say for ionic4

Comment: It should work still I think. I assumed you were using angularfire2?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work, obj.title says "Property 'title' does not exist on type 'unknown[]'.ts(2339)"

Comment: Yeah, my bad, the observable emits all the values, I'm going to edit my first post

Comment: obj.title doesnt exist on unknow :(

Comment: And if you try to type this.af.collection ? By using this.af.collection<YourObjectType>('objects')....